# scipy.optimize: using lists vs ndarrays

Tags: python, scipy

I have been solving some minimisation problems using scipy.optimize and have (I'm not entirely sure why!) been specifying my initial guess as a list. For example:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective_function(x):
    a = x[0]
    b = x[1]
    return a**2 + b**2

x0 = [1, 2]

sol = minimize(objective_function, x0)
```

In the examples I have tried, this doesn't cause any problems. From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), however, I see that the initial guess is meant to be an ndarray. Can any problems be caused by continuing to specify initial guesses as lists?

Comment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/75ef7dbcbee1fa5114de86a3238333978350056a/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py#L496

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list is fine.  As you can see in the code that @talonmies linked to in a comment, the first thing that `minimize` does is convert `x0` to an array with

```
x0 = np.asarray(x0)
```

The documentation should probably describe the expected type of `x0` as "array_like" (a description used throughout the NumPy and SciPy documentation), meaning roughly "something that can be converted to an array of numbers".